# Android Studio UI

Tags: android, android-layout

I am kind of new to Android Studio and I have been having lots of issues with the designer. I format everything in the drag and drop designer and then as soon as I press play and run the project, all the buttons and edit texts just bunches up in the top left corner. I've searched around online and it looks like I have to learn how to use linear layouts or relative layouts and XML. Can someone explain this to me or maybe point me in the direction of a tutorial?

Comment: You need to actually learn XML.  When you drag and drop, its turned into XML-  badly.  Its easier, faster, and more maintainable to just write good xml from scratch.  I've been doing android for almost 8 years now, I haven't even looked at the graphical tool in years-  it just isn't an effective way of writing software.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the root element for the .XML file is a ConstraintLayout. You should read about LinearLayouts and then RelativeLayout to get started. To explain in simple terms, a LL uses a linear heirarchy to stack views vertically or horizontally amongst each other. A RL is used to position views relative to each other, ie, the position of one view depends on position of another view. ConstraintLayout is the latest and most powerful one, which is used to reduce deep nesting of views by defining certain constraints amongst views in the layout.
Also, for future question posts, please include code snippets which you think are causing the problem. It helps a lot. Cheers!